# Storing text cleanly into mysql TEXT field

Tags: php, mysql

Im attempting to store the following word in a TEXT field in my MYSQL db table:

> Valentine’s

But for some reason it stores as the following:

> Valentineâs

Is there a PHP function I can use to clean the string before i store it in the database..

> the CHARSET of the table is latin1

Comment: What is the charset of that column?

Comment: Also, how are you inserting the value? Hope you're using parameterized queries which do all of the necessary escaping for you...

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars();` is what you're looking for I guess.